# How can I display data from ajax in my alert window while adding data dynamically?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm fetching data from php script as follows:

```
$.ajax({
  url: './fetchData.php', 
  type: "POST",
  data: {
    mail: mail
  },
  dataType:'text',
  success: function(ans)
  {
    var data = JSON.parse(ans);

    $('ul.dropdown-alerts').html('');

    $.each(data, function(i, v) {
        $('ul.dropdown-alerts').append('<li><a href="#"><div><i class="fa fa-comment fa-fw"></i>' + v.Content + '<span class="pull-right text-muted small">' + v.Date + '</span></div></a></li>');
        $('ul.dropdown-alerts').append('<li class="divider"></li>');
    });     

$('ul.dropdown-alerts').append('<li><a class="text-center" href="more.php"><strong>See More</strong></a></li>');                
    }});
```

However, in my json string I have more than `Content` and `Date`. In general I have:

```
[{"cid":"1","Content":"esj","commercial_resource":"","Date":"2015-10-21 19:00:00","Price":"0.00"},{"cid":"1","Content":"esj","commercial_resource":"","Date":"2015-10-21 19:00:00","Price":"0.00"},
{"cid":"1","Content":"esj","commercial_resource":"","Date":"2015-10-21 19:00:00","Price":"0.00"},
{"cid":"1","Content":"esj","commercial_resource":"","Date":"2015-10-21 19:00:00","Price":"0.00"}, etc.]
```

And I would like to display alert with cid of selected row when user click the hyperlink in it. How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any information related to the record that you want to use later, store on the object as a data-* element.  You can later then reference it and use it however you like.

Just like your referencing the v.Content on the object, you can reference the v.cid on the object and put it either on the link directly or the parent li

`'<a data-cid="'+ v.cid +'"></a>' <-- $(this).data('cid')
'<li data-cid="'+ v.cid +'"><a></a></li>' <-- $(this).closest('li').data('cid')`

Little dummy example of giving an event access to an object later...

```js
var data = [
    { name: 'Me', location: 'Here' }
    , { name: 'You', location: 'There' }
    , { name: 'We', location: 'Internet' }
];

$('ul').append($.map(data, function(record){
    var $li = $('<li>');
    
    $li.text(record.name);
    
    $li.on('click', function(){
        console.log(record);
    });
    
    return $li;
}));
```

Comment: Ok, but how can I exactly referecnce the specific id when user clicks the specific link?

Comment: Thanks, one more thing - how can I pass the whole data object instead of only cid and then refer to it in jquery?

Comment: I would suggest either putting the fields you want as data elements, or construct your click event to provide the object for later use.